# How to delete row ids with appended date in Siebel

Tags: siebel, rowid

I have few row ids in Siebel like '1-36THIX10/30/2014'.

This is program(Campaign related) scheduled in future. Now I want to delete the records with such row ids (suffixed with date) .

The Siebel tables involved are S_EVT_ACT, S_MKTG_SRVR_TSK, S_srm_request

Can anybody please tell me which table will it be stored in so that I can delete such records?

Comment: a question. What method you want to follow? PL/SQL? or RCR? or Stub-program?

Answer (score 0):

From which applet you are getting the RowId , find that applet from the tool.Go to theBC of the applet .There you can find the name of the table.

Comment: The table use is S_EVT_ACT but these entries are not present in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Its a different table for each entity: S_EVT_ACT is Action. Are the records spread across multiple entities ?

Tables: S_MKTG_SRVR_TSK, S_srm_request are related to server management, these tables should not be modified from backend, as they are used by various components.

Comment: My programs are scheduled daily. For example now in S_EVT_ACT I can see entry for tomorrow's scheduled run. If I want to delete future scheduled programs I need to know the table. Correct me If i m missing sth.